# Time Manager in QGIS works but does not display timestamp on map

Tags: qgis, timemanager

I am using QGIS 3.12 to run the Time Manager plugin. The data is formatted correctly in Y-M-D form and Time Manager runs as intended (data values change with time); however, timestamp is not displayed in the bottom right corner despite "display frame start time on map" being clicked on. 
 
 I checked "time display options" and selected a color to contrast the map background. 
 I also tried with different basemaps, and without a basemap, and the timestamp is not displayed in all cases.


After much toggling around, selecting W view in "time display options" makes the timestamp barely visible off the frame. I have tried changing the map resolution and even the projection system, but the timestamp appears almost hidden to a corner. Changing the display option to any other locations, such as NW, E, W, makes it disappear again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not ideal, but after trying unsuccessfully with version 3.10, I was able to export the project and run it on QGIS version 2.18 without any timestamp display issues.